# How to apply class weights in linear classifier for binary classification?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

This is the linear classifier that I am using to perform binary classification, here is code snippet:

```
my_optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate)
my_optimizer = tf.contrib.estimator.clip_gradients_by_norm(my_optimizer,5.0)
# Create a linear classifier object
linear_classifier = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(
          feature_columns = feature_columns, 
          optimizer = my_optimizer 
          )
linear_classifier.train(input_fn = training_input_fn, steps = steps)
```

The dataset is imbalanced, there are only two classes yes/no. The number of NO class examples are 36548 while number of YES class examples are 4640.

How can I apply balancing to this data? I have been searching around and I could find stuff related to class weights etc but I couldn't find how can I create class weights and how to apply to the train method of tensor flow.

Here is how I am calculating losses:

```
training_probabilities = linear_classifier.predict(input_fn = training_predict_input_fn)
training_probabilities = np.array([item['probabilities'] for item in training_probabilities])

validation_probabilities = linear_classifier.predict(input_fn=validation_predict_input_fn)
validation_probabilities = np.array([item['probabilities'] for item in validation_probabilities])

training_log_loss = metrics.log_loss(training_targets, training_probabilities)
validation_log_loss = metrics.log_loss(validation_targets, validation_probabilities)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are using the `log_loss` function from [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.log_loss.html) for computing your loss. If that is the case you can add class weights by using the argument `sample_weight` and pass on an array containing the weight to be given for each data point. `sample_weight` is an rolled out version of `class_weights`. You can compute `sample_weight` array by passing on the sample weights as given [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_sample_weight.html).

Add the following lines to your code:

```
sample_wts = compute_sample_weight("balanced", training_targets)
training_log_loss = metrics.log_loss(training_targets, training_probabilities, sample_weight= sample_wts)
```

Comment: training examples is 28832 x 2 whereas training targets is 28832 x 1, the sample weights generated are 28832 x 1 in size, can you elaborate what it means? This will be used to solve class imbalance problem right?

Comment: when you say `class_weights` you essentially give a dictionary having the weights for each class say `{0:0.1, 1: 5}`. Now let's come back to `sample_weights`let's assume you have 10 data points `y_true = [0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0]` what sample weight will do is just creates an array whose elements are `[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,5,5, 0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]` and yeah this will solve the problem of class imbalance.

Comment: Thanks, if I follow the above code snippet I see that compute_sample_weight just simply assigns weights to the data points depending on which class they belong, but keep in mind I have not explicitly mentioned the class_weight anywhere, how they are computing this?

Comment: It is computed within the `compute_sample_weight` function. Here I have specified  `balanced` as the `class_weight` parameter which adjusts  adjust weights inversely proportional to class frequencies in the input data as `n_samples / (n_classes * np.bincount(y))`. For more details please refer to https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_sample_weight.html